Stripe Test account ID deletion issue
I deleted a test account but unfortunately cant get rid of account ID. Im getting 400 erros code and this . Trying to figure out how to fix this issue so I can connect the correct ID to my website. Thank Ya!!! :
resource_missing - account
No such account: 'acct_1PbVTECiGpUV7uyt'
Was this useful?YesNo
{
"account": "acct_1PbVTECiGpUV7uyt",
"return_url": """"
"type": "account_onboarding""account_onboarding"
"refresh_url": ""
}
Response body
{
"error": {
"resource_missing"

"https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing"

"No such account: 'acct_1PbVTECiGpUV7uyt'"

"account"

"request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs/req_4H0ItIBVexVSMe?t=1721268431",

"invalid_request_error"

}
}

What do you mean you can't get rid of account ID? Your own application is passing in that account ID, so you'll want to figure out where are you retrieving/storing that account ID from.

It was the ID to a test account that was deleted days ago. Couldn't wipe out the ID even though I created a new live one. Actually I'm going to start from the beginning and create an account from scratch.

It seems like you were trying to create an account link with an ID of an already deleted account.
I'm not sure what you mean by "connect the correct ID to my website". You might want to create a new connected account, so that you can create an account link for it.

Thank ya!! I'm actually going to start from scratch and create a new account. Tried to figure out how to correct the issue and nothing worked.

Tried to complete the onboarding for my website by connecting my stripe account to it.
